# Is there any function in jquery I can search child elements text and filter all the child ements by search key?

Tags: jquery

For example my html is like below,

```
<div id="mainDiv">
   <div id="1">This is animal page</div>
   <div id="2">No animal here</div>
   <div id="3">Jame Bond</div>
   <div id="4">Simple Bond</div>
</div>
```

And I have a `input` field like this

```
<input type="text" id="search">
```

While searching anything it has to list the result in other div.

Like when I search for `keyword bond` it should show like below

```
<div id="mainDiv">
   <div id="3">Jame Bond</div>
   <div id="4">Simple Bond</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: You should make use of ajax along with server side language like php to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little further with Blender's answer,
Try this

```
<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="search(this.value);">
  <div id="mainDiv">
     <div id="1">This is animal page</div>
     <div id="2">No animal here</div>
     <div id="3">Jame Bond</div>
     <div id="4">Simple Bond</div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function search(text) {
       var search_string = text;
       var all = $('#mainDiv > div');

       all.css({ "display": "none" });

       var $matched = $('#mainDiv > div').filter(function () {
          return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search_string) !== -1;
       });

       $matched.css({ "display": "block" });
     }
</script>
```

Demo link : http://jsbin.com/ocugug/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and make a simple filtering function:

```
var search_string = 'bond';
var $matched = $('#mainDiv > div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search_string) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: why didnt you ask him "So what have you tried?" as your previous post

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     $("#mainDiv div").hide();
     $("#mainDiv div:contains("+$("#search").val()+")").show();
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/abagel/1/edit)